# Select without a FROM clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

in **SQL Server** is possible to execute a SELECT, without reference to a table; something like:

```
Select 1.2 +3, 'my dummy string'
```

As **Oracle** does not allow a SELECT without a FROM, I use the dual table for this type of operation; something like:

```
Select 1,2+3, 'my dummy string' FROM DUAL
```

There is a better way of doing this type of query? it is good practice to use the dual table?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

No, in `Oracle` there is no `SELECT` without `FROM`.

Using the `dual` table is a good practice.

`dual` is an in-memory table. If you don't select `DUMMY` from it, it uses a special access path (`FAST DUAL`) which requires no `I/O`.

Once upon a time, `dual` had two records (hence the name) and was intended to serve as a dummy recordset to duplicate records being joined with.

Now it has but one record, but you can still generate an arbitrary number of rows with it:

```
SELECT  level
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY
        level <= 100
```

`MySQL` also supports `dual` (as well as the fromless syntax).

Comment: Didn't know about the history of dual. Just make sure dual only contains one row. I have seen dual tables with all kind of stuff in it. A guarantee for a long and fun bug hunt.

Comment: Sort of like when /dev/null gets replaced by a normal file?

Comment: `@Paul Tomblin`: worse than that. dual uses different access path depending on whether you select `dummy` from it of not.

Comment: FAST DUAL is supported since Oracle 10g. In 9i DUAL is just an ordinary table.

Comment: And here is a good link from Tom Kyte that goes into some aspects of Dual:  http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1562813956388

Comment: "Once upon a time, dual had two records" .. dual is a good ol' man

Comment: Do you have any idea if Oracle has ever considered dropping the FROM clause requirement?  Selecting from dual seems so ridiculous and hacky to me I can't believe Oracle has never fixed this.

Answer (score 11):

don't forget that most of the times you don't actually need to use SELECT.

Instead of:

```
SELECT sysdate INTO l_date FROM dual;
SELECT CASE WHEN i = j THEN 0 ELSE 1 END INTO l_foo FROM dual;
...
```

you can use

```
l_date := sysdate;
l_foo  := CASE WHEN i = j THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
...
```

Comment: +1 Don't execute a query if you're not getting any data from any tables, and you can do it all in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 4):

> it is good practice to use the dual
>   table

Yes, the dual table is usually used for this exact purpose. It's pretty standard in Oracle when you have no table to select from.

Comment: That's why I never use Oracle. It is already fundamentally dead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the dual table is the usual way to do this in Oracle. As a matter of fact, it was introduced just for this.

The main advantage of DUAL is that the optimizer in Oracle knows it is special, so queries using it can be faster than if you used a single-row table you made yourself. Other than that, there's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you gotta use dual.  it is used when you need to run SQL that does not have a table name.  I can't say I use it much other than in SQL scripts to echo out the date something is ran or something stupid like that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, SQL Server's implementation is non-standard. The [SQL-92 Standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (Section 7.9) requires a FROM clause in a SELECT statement. DUAL is Oracle's way of providing a table to select from to get a scalar row.