# Oracle, Make date time's first day of its month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a datevariable, I would like to have convert it to first day of its monh,

- Eg: 10/10/2010 -> 01/10/2010
- Eg: 31/07/2010 -> 01/07/2010

Answer (score 59, accepted):

According to http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html, this should work a dandy...

```
SELECT TRUNC(yourDateField, 'MONTH') FROM yourTable
```

Comment: As @ ErwinBrandstetter points out, it's in the documentation.  No need to link to to unofficial sites.

Comment: I linked the first match that I got when I googled it.  Being that it provides the answer, I don't see that as even remotely problematic.

Comment: The PSOUG site used to be a reputable site when Dan Morgan maintained it.  That is no longer the case.  Not that it now contains false information, just that it's not being kept up to date.  In my opinion it is better to reference the official documentation rather than a site of uncertain provenance, even if it is the first hit in a Google Search.  Google Searches throw up all sorts of things.

Answer (score 9):

```
SQL> select to_date('31/07/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;

TO_DATE('
---------
31-JUL-10

SQL> select trunc(to_date('31/07/2010', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM') from dual;

TRUNC(TO_
---------
01-JUL-10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one

```
select trunc(sysdate, 'MM')firstday , trunc(last_DAY(sysdate)) lastday from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT trunc(to_date('22-AUG-03'), 'MON') FROM dual;
```

More in the [manual](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions242.htm#i1002084).
About Oracle needing a dummy `FROM`: [Select without a FROM clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881853/oracle-select-without-from)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example:

```
select trunc(to_date('15.11.2019', 'DD.MM.YYYY'), 'MONTH') from dual;
```