# Oracle SQL Roll back date to beginning of month best practice CONCAT & SUBSTR or TRUNC

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a field `date` which is a date format.

It outputs like this for example.

```
09-NOV-14
```

Now what i want the output to be is any date rolled back to the 1st of its month.

```
01-NOV-14
```

What i did to achieve this is

```
CONCAT('01',SUBSTR(table.date,3))
```

Is this the most efficient/best practice way of doing this?

Comment: Why did the year change from 14 to 09?

Comment: @Siyual Because i cant type :)

Comment: maybe this works for you: trunc(date,'month')

Comment: As a general rule, date functions are pretty good in most decent DBMS. You hardly ever need to do string manipulation.

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Thanks that worked perfectly! Put it in an answer and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

moved from comment to answer:

```
trunc(date,'month')
```

Answer (score 2):

The output format you get when a date is cast to string is configurable:

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
---------
26-NOV-14

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
2014-11-26 16:15:44
```

... thus your approach is not particularly robust. To use date functions (rather than string manipulation) please check [Make date time's first day of its month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850551/oracle-make-date-times-first-day-of-its-month).

Comment: A great answer but i used the above as it was purely for a one time report

Comment: You're free to accept the answer that better solves your question, but we're both suggesting the same solution.