# Conditional INSERT INTO using SELECT 'WHERE NOT' fails

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have this conditional INSERT INTO using SELECT 'WHERE NOT' that fails. I got the syntax of this by trying to follow examples I found on Google which claim they work.  I can't figure out where the syntax is wrong, unless what I am doing is not supported?

```
INSERT INTO ENV (ENV_ID, ENV_NAME, SSO_URL, ENV_NAME_LOWER)
SELECT '99', 'Blah', 'https://blah.com:443', 'production'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ENV WHERE ENV_ID = '99');
```

And here is the error I get in Oracle:

```
Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
```

UPDATE:
Got a satisfactory answer but couldn't completely get it working due to another error:  `ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns`

Comment: Syntax in sql is `INSERT INTO` and then `VALUES`

Comment: Ok, so you are implying that the only way to do this might be using a MERGE statement?

Comment: @RichardHamilton OP's syntax is correct in this regard, you may feed an insert statement with a query result in sql.

Comment: The problem is `select ... where...` without the `from`.  Either tweak your sql statement or use `from dual`...

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1881862/1073631

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of the outer query is incorrect due to a missing `from` clause. That needs to be specified notwithstanding that you are using literal values only. Oracle provides the 'dual' table for this purpose:

```
INSERT INTO ENV (ENV_ID, ENV_NAME, SSO_URL, ENV_NAME_LOWER)
     SELECT '99', 'Blah', 'https://blah.com:443', 'production'
       FROM DUAL
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ENV WHERE ENV_ID = '99')
          ;
```

The statement will fail iff the env record tested for exists.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the syntax is correct.  I think I am limited by my database permissions because I get this error:  ORA-54013: INSERT operation disallowed on virtual columns

Comment: Well, maybe, some of the columns you referenced are, you know, [virtual](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)? Use this query: `select column_name, virtual_column from user_tab_cols where  table_name = 'ENV'`. Virtual columns will have 'YES'.