# Oracle missing FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create a CTE without a `FROM`, and if not isn't that the whole point of a CTE in the first place?

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS col1, 2 AS col2
)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM cte;

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

It seems a quick-fix for this is just adding `FROM DUAL` whenever needed. Is that what's supposed to be done?

Comment: You cannot omit the FROM clause.  use FROM DUAL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select without a FROM clause in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881853/select-without-a-from-clause-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what `dual` is supposed to be used for.

> Selecting from the DUAL table is useful for computing a constant
> expression with the SELECT statement. Because DUAL has only one row,
> the constant is returned only once.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm